# Is there an alternative to regexp_replace() and regexp_extract() in sas?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have

```
select
    regexp_replace(city_name,',','') as city_name
  , regexp_extract(regexp_replace(postal_cd,',','') ,'^(.*?)(?:-)(.*)$',1) as zip5
```

This works in Hue but I want to get the same output in SAS, so what can be the replacement for `regexp_replace` and `regexp_extract` function to work in sas?

I tried using replace but that is not working in sas

Comment: https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Use SAS functions `prxchange` to replace, and `prxsubstr` to extract.

Replacing a matching character with nothing can also be done with `COMPRESS`
Extract words from a delimited string can also be done with `SCAN`

The non regular expression ways (COMPRESS, SCAN) are generally faster because they are very specific in their implementation.

Example:

Use COMPRESS and SCAN

```
data have;
  city = 'Spring,field';
  zip = '1,2,3,4,5-6,7,8,9';
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select
    compress(city,',') as city
  , scan(compress(zip,','),1,'-') as zip5
  from 
    have
  ;
```

[image]

Comment: The `scan` function accepts multiple separators, if you like.